# SQL COPY cannot open file in pgAdmin4. But the import tool works. Why?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

When I write a query, nothing works. I can only import using the built in import tool by right-clicking the table. I want to do the following however I get the error below. If I import with the tool I cannot use a WHERE clause. Am I missing a filepath? I've also tried the psql tool and cannot get it to work at all.

```
COPY supervisor_salaries (town, supervisor, salary)
FROM 'supervisor_salaries.csv'
WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER)
WHERE town = 'New Brillig';
```

> ERROR:  could not open file "supervisor_salaries.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
> HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.

SQL state: 58P01

using version 7 of pgAdmin4 and PostgreSQL v15. All newly installed today.

Comment: yes you are missing something like '/var/lib/postgresql/supervisor_salaries.csv'``

Comment: and teh systac for client side is identical

Comment: You showed the same statement and same error twice.  Was one of those supposed to be different?

Comment: Actually, I finally got it to work after reading another post online about setting user permissions for the file to 'Everyone'. I'm just wondering if there's some setting I should have so that I don't need to do this on every .csv file I create.

Comment: The error message tells you the issue: *HINT: COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.*. The docs provide further information [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html): *...The file must be accessible by the PostgreSQL user (the user ID the server runs as) and the name must be specified from the viewpoint of the server. ...*. Read the entire documentation for further enlightenment.